# Where is allocateIds in the Google Cloud Datastore java library?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I moving some data from Mysql to the Datastore and for this data migaration I want to keep the old Ids from Mysql.

I found this note [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers:)

```
Instead of using key name strings or generating numeric IDs automatically, advanced applications may sometimes wish to assign their own numeric IDs manually to the entities they create. Be aware, however, that there is nothing to prevent Datastore from assigning one of your manual numeric IDs to another entity. The only way to avoid such conflicts is to have your application obtain a block of IDs with the allocateIds() method. Cloud Datastore's automatic ID generator will keep track of IDs that have been allocated with these methods and will avoid reusing them for another entity, so you can safely use such IDs without conflict.
```

So allocateIds seems perfect for what I am trying to do. I want to use the method to allocate all the auto incremented ids from Mysql so that I can then use the datastore Id generator without worrying about collision.

However I can't find this method anywhere. I am using the cloud datastore java library as a standalone library, without using the app engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Datastore API does not expose a method for reserving a user-specified ID. The `AllocateIds` method picks IDs for you.

One possible approach would be to assign the MySQL-generated IDs to the `name` (string) field in your keys. Cloud Datastore never auto-assigns the `name` field. The downside is that your application code would be responsible for generating future values.

Comment: I am just confused because at the bottom of this paragraph: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers
It says that you can allocate manual ids using allocateIds, but I can't find the method.

Comment: There is a method `allocateId` on `com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore`, but it will only accept an incomplete key (one which does not already specify the ID or name). The paragraph you linked to is slightly misleading on that front -- I'll see about getting that fixed.

Comment: @EdDavisson - The allocateId method accepts both IncompleteKey and Key (because Key extends IncompleteKey) and it happily returns a Key with a "new" ID. Any ID you set in the input is pretty much discarded. Perhaps this method also needs a fix to reject Key objects (that have a ID).

Comment: @SaiPullabhotla: Thanks for pointing that out! I've filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1567

Answer (score 0):

The google example code provides code like below to auto-generate an id or key using com.google.cloud.datastore (gen2 java):

```
public static Key getAutoGenKey(String projectId, String kindName) {
    
    Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService().getDatastore();

    // Code below taken from Google, here:
    //    https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/main/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/datastore/snippets/DatastoreSnippets.java

    KeyFactory keyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind(kindName).setProjectId(projectId);
    IncompleteKey incompleteKey = keyFactory.newKey();

    // let cloud datastore automatically assign an id:
    Key key = datastore.allocateId(incompleteKey);
    
    return key;
}
```